# Does Flutter Support iOS Features?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-dependencies, flutter-sliver

I am starting to work on one big project which includes Sirikit, Game Center, Fingerprint, health kit and home kit etc. 
So my doubt is can I implement those features & other features which are provided by ios using the flutter..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no - you could definitely use some and probably all of those, but you'll have to write [Platform Channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/). I use fingerprint for example in my app.

There may exist plugins for some of the functionality - see the [flutter packages page](https://pub.dartlang.org/flutter/).

Answer (score 1):

Flutter can't generate bitcode. So, it can't integrate features like Siri, interactive notifications, watchOS, tvOS, Today and other modern extensions.

It compiles like it was before 2015. Before iOS extensions. With same limitations.